# Any JavaScript libraries similar to Tangle.js?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking at using Tangle.js for a project, either with Angular or with Ember. I've been having a difficult finding anything similar via Google to compare with, so I was wondering if anyone here knew of other possibilities.

Comment: Did you find anything?

Comment: No, we decided on a different route shortly after I posted this.